# How to build DetachedCriteria with aggregation of foregin field?

Tags: hibernate, grails

Tables structure:

[image: tables]

To aggregate the total amount of goods with SQL is easy:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(i.count) as total_goods
FROM operation op
    INNER JOIN order ord 
        ON op.orderId = ord.id
    INNER JOIN item itm 
        ON itm.orderId = ord.id
WHERE
    op.dateCreated < '2015-07-01 00:00:00'
```

But how to do that with `DetachedCriteria`?

```
int getTotalGoods(DetachedCriteria filteredOperations) {
   // already contains date filter
   filteredOperations.build {
       projections {
           // 'Order' entity has one-to-many association 'items'
           sum('order.items.count')
       }
   }.list().get(0) ?: 0
}
```

This code fails with:

> could not resolve property: order.items.count of: com.Operation